# Laravel 5..1.3 after fresh install kernel.php adds an extra ::class on lines and editor complains syntax

Tags: laravel-5

I went to the `Kernel.php` file and (yet again) the files are changed compared to 5.1 so now it shows lines like this one:

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
```

but my editor complains about that:

> word 'class' expecting identifier T_STRING

The former version of `Kernel.php` did not have that extra `::class` in any of the protected `$middleware` array,

So, actually it should be fine like it is but now that I have to add my own lines, that is when I get wary about it, as I am now to register one class that I added in the middlware (for localization locale stuff)
and it should be like this?

```
'App\Http\Middleware\Language::class'
```

the file I added in the Middleware is of course, `Language.php`

so, in one word, what is that extra added `::class` syntax? will it be ok my adding it like I did? This is so new that I dont find anything on googling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can still keep your old notations, it's not a problem. But as 5.1 is a LTS package, Laravel wants to use most of the new PHP features, thus PHP 5.4 will be deprecated soon. One of the new features of PHP 5.5 is that `::class` notation.

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class):

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name
>   resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name
>   of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly
>   useful with namespaced classes.

Example:

```
namespace NS {
    class ClassName {}
    echo ClassName::class; // Output -> NS\ClassName
}
```

About your question you should add it like below:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class
];
```

Also about your editor, upgrade and set your PHP interpreter to 5.5 and any errors that your editor may raise will be removed.